# No me funciona el metodo Array.equals

Tags: java, array, método

he leído por internet que existe un método que compara dos arrays para ver si son iguales(array.equals). Lo he intentado implementar y me lo cuenta como que no existe. El código es el siguiente:

```
public static void resuelto(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario){
        int matrizRespuesta[]=crearTabla();
        int matrizDelUsuario[]=pedirTabla();
        if(Arrays.equals(matrizRespuesta,matrizDelUsuario)) {
            System.out.println("Lo has hecho genial!! Las dos cadenas son identicas");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Mala suerte todavía no son identicas las cadenas, intentalo de nuevo ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Que significa `me lo cuenta como que no existe`? ¿Has importado la clase Arrays?

Comment: Resuelto... Gracias soy nuevo aún y no he caído en importar esa clase...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-)  de la clase [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) cumple la función que deseas:

> [Arrays.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-) Devuelve verdadero si las dos matrices especificadas de ints son  iguales entre sí.

Si te muestra un error mencionando que la clase no existe o "Cannot find Symbol"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto indica que no has agregado el `import` de la clase para poder utilizarla en tu programa, agrégalo y de esta forma podrás utilizar los métodos de esta clase:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación!